# .htaccess redirect based on referrer

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, referrer

I'm having some troubles getting my htaccess rules to work in the intended way. My goal is to redirect any user from example.com to their intended destination that they accessed. However, if the user's referrer is not example.com, I would like it to redirect to a page on my site.

Correct referrer? > URL accessed

Incorrect/unset referrer? > Login page.

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https?://([^.]+\.)*example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net/login.php [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://([^.]+\.)*example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

However this results in a redirect loop.
Am I doing something wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Still no luck, any ideas?